# Assigning multiple sizes to one product SKU

Tags: custom-options, multiselect-attribute, tags

We sell shoes online.  Some shoes come in European sizes (37, 38, 39 etc.) while others come in U.S sizes of 7, 8, 9 etc.

We have a search option whereby shoppers can select to view only shoes in their size.  We would like to ensure that if a woman selects for example a size 8 that all SKUs with a European size of 38 is also displayed in the results.

Any suggestion of how best to do this in Magento?  Can this be accomplished using tags or the custom options attribute or something else?

Answer (score 1):

For me there seems to be two questions here.

Firstly how to structure products with regards of grouping and configuration.

Secondly attribute conversion between different countries.

**`Product structure`**

What I would do if I was in your position here would be to create configurable products with each simple product as a product with the different sizes. Example here you would have.

1. Green Shoe (SKU: green-shoe)
2. Green Shoe size 8 (SKU: green-shoe-8)
3. Green Shoe size 9 (SKU: green-shoe-9)

The "simple" products which have the sizes would not be accessible individually but would be attached to the configurable product. This should work out of the box with regards to search and attribute filtering. Down side here is that you can end up with a very large catalog (only seen by the admin) with each size being a separate product.

**`Attribute Conversion`**

This one is a bit more tricky and I have never had to achieve something similar. One option is to split the sizes by store so you have a store based in the USA and a store based in the EU. The EU store uses EU sizes and the USA store uses the appropriate sizes. Then simply change the values for each store. Personally I would go this way as it is not very often that someone would search for US sizes but pay in € as they are on a site inside the EU. If you think about this with regards to pricing and pricing conversion.